# PostgreSQL remove elements from array column that matches (big) subquery

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  product_ids integer[] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_customer_id" PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
CREATE INDEX "IDX_product_ids" ON sales USING gin(product_ids);
```

There are 5M rows in that table, `product_ids` array contains 200 elements on average. Suppose I need to delete specific retired product ids from every `sales` row. List of retired products is produced by subquery to `products` table, which returns around 30M records.

Now I'm doing it like this (pseudocode):

```
create table sales_heap ...
insert into sales_heap select customer_id, unnest(product_ids) from sales;
create index product_id on sales_heap ...
delete from sales_heap where product_id in (select product_id from products ...);
truncate table sales;
insert into sales select customer_id, array_agg(product_id) from sales_heap group by customer_id;
drop table sales_heap;
```

I've also tried some CTE and nested FOR-based approaches, but got out of memory error each time (8 Gb work_mem). The fact that `array_remove` doesn't allow array argument for items being deleted is a pain too.

Can anyone think of a more beautiful way to do that without hitting memory limits?

Comment: I know this is probably not what you want to hear, but this would be a lot easier (and probably more efficient) if you had normalized your sales table.

Comment: Waited for that suggestion :) You probably mean DEnormalizing, because product ids will duplicate. That was first table structure I tried, but queries like "give me all customers who have all 2 specific products" were unacceptably complex and slow without arrays.

Comment: I _did_ mean normalize. Storing a list of values in a single column is violating first normal form because `product_ids` is not an atomic attribute. But for the queries you mention this is probably the better model. But the cost for de-normalizing is an increased overhead in writing, which you have just found out. The only (probably **terribly** slow) workaround I can think of is to delete items in batches. Or do the aggregation in your pseudocode in batches (e.g. 500 customers at a time)

Comment: It's arguable whether array is a non-atomic attribute, but product id duplication obviously violates 3NF. The heap way works fine, but is very slow and not safe. I believe that there's some bigger issue with postgre always materialising subqueries with transformations, which is not how, for example, mssql works. But it's just a guess. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hmm, regarding the "issue with subquery materialising": I would be highly surprised if SQL Server did _not_ materialize a subquery that returns 30 million rows.  (btw: it's Postgres, never Postgre)

Comment: One thing you might want to try is the [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension. It provides an operator to subtract one array from another. But you would still need to keep 30 million distinct product_ids in an array - don't know if that would work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. Regarding materialisation, I've meant only materialisation in RAM. Never seen out  of system memory errors in mssql in cases like that, wish postgres would be that way.